# Why DolphinDB MySQL plugin is not loaded

Tags: mysql, plugins, dolphindb

My code is as shown below. After loading the plugin, the execution of  connect raised an error: Cannot recognize function mysql::connect. Why the loading fails?

[the code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJeTl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `go` statement after `loadPlugin`. The statement splits the script into blocks to parse and execute the blocks in order. Therefore, `loadPlugin` can be executed first before `go`, then the subsequent code is parsed and executed. The corrected code is:

```
loadPlugin("/usr/local/DolphinDB/server/plugins/mysql/PluginMySQL.txt")
go
conn = mysql::connect("192.168.101.17",3306,"root","333","stock")
mysql::showTables(conn)
```